# Element not staying within a DIV

Tags: html, css

I am using Smart Report Maker (www.mysqlreports.com) to create some basic reporting for a web app - when I include the reports into my template the menu for the report behaves very oddly and will not stay within the enclosing DIV. The odd thing is that the table itself does but the menu does not so I suspect it is a styling issue applied in Javascript to the menu.

Code is linked below to a text file as it is over 42000 characters so won't allow me to paste here.

Any ideas what is causing this to happen or how I can fix?

http://www.dowzell.com/stack/repaudit.txt

This shows how the menu should look above the table when outside the template[outside the template http://www.dowzell.com/stack/img1.jpg](http://www.dowzell.com/stack/img1.jpg)

This shows how it actually looks when embedded
[inside the template http://www.dowzell.com/stack/img2.jpg](http://www.dowzell.com/stack/img2.jpg)

This shows the outputted code on screen which shows the menu has moved outside all the divs despite being placed inside the div in the above code.
[firebug http://www.dowzell.com/stack/img3.jpg](http://www.dowzell.com/stack/img3.jpg)

Thanks
Jason

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: What do you mean that the menu will not stay in the enclosing div? I can't see that in the screenshots as I don't know the way your menu is supposed to look like. Also which one is the enclosing div that you talk about? As has been already said it is difficult to help you with so little information and no code.

Comment: It must have to do something with the position:absolute

Comment: Have you checked that the code validates?

Comment: The menu is supposed to look like the first screenshot - placed above the table but it appears as in the second screenshot when embedded into the template and placed inside a DIV. I will edit the question now and post code though there is tons...

Comment: If I understand correctly, once you add your report to your template, it looks like that some javascript manipulates the html and throws your menu at the  bottom of the page. If this is the case you have to identify which function is doing that and why. By looking at your code in the screenshot I see a lot of elements positioned 'absolute' and in the code you posted in the text file, the function that seems to do that is the MbrSetUp or the CreateMenuStructure function?

Comment: Just looked at CreateMenuStructure function and changed    Location.document.body.appendChild(MmbrCntnr)} to Location.document.getElementById("mws-container").appendChild(MmbrCntnr)} and it now appears within the div but the menu items are still all on top of each other so one thing fixed (thank you @effectica), now to figure out why the menu doesn't space properly

Comment: Is the page in question live online?