# Form not staying within a DIV (Works in IE 9 but not Chrome or IE11)

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a grid-based layout created in CSS (used [this](http://j4n.co/blog/Creating-your-own-css-grid-system) article at [j4n.co](http://j4n.co) created 6/2014, so I don't *think* the CSS is outdated, but I could be wrong.)

Overall, it displays fine, but I run into a problem when trying to place forms within a DIV. Here are a couple of snippets of code:

HTML: (taken from within PHP, but [the problem recreates](http://jsfiddle.net/1mdLynt1/2/) as below)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="group">Group Name</div>
<div class="col-1">
    <p class="item">Item Name
        <br>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" class="pullup">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="' . htmlspecialchars($itemID) . '"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="userIDnum" value="' . htmlspecialchars($userIDnum) . '"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="groupName" value="' . htmlspecialchars($group_name) . '"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="itemName" value="' . htmlspecialchars($item_name) . '"></input>
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile"></input>
            <br>Name:
            <input type="text" name="displayName"></input>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1200px;}

.group {
   background-color: #FFDCDC;
   width: 16.66%;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;}

/*-- our cleafix hack -- */
.row:before, .row:after {
   content:"";
   display: table;
   clear:both;}

[class*='col-'] {
   float: left;
   min-height: 1px;
   width: 16.66%;
   /*-- our gutter -- */
   padding: 12px;
   background-color: #FFDCDC;}

.col-1 {
   width: 16.66%;}

.outline, .outline * {
   outline: 0px solid #dddddd;}

p.item {
   height: 200px;}

/*-- some extra column content styling --*/
[class*='col-'] > p {
   background-color: #FFC2C2;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;}

form.pullup {
   outline: 5px solid #000000;
   display: table-cell;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mdLynt1/2/) showing my problem. I'd like the dark outlined form to be within the darker red box.

**From "Questions that may already have your answer"**:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087943/element-not-staying-within-a-div) OP did not follow up on his/her question. I tried the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757646/button-not-staying-within-div) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942514/page-layout-works-in-ie-and-firefox-but-not-chrome) question without success.

From **Similar Questions**, I did not see anything that seemed pertinent. If there is a question that might help that I missed, please point me to it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is form tags are not allowed inside p tags, because p tags should not contain any block elements. The easy solution is to change the .item tag to a div and update your CSS.

Check out [this fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zn679fqp/1/).

```
<div class="row">
<div class="group">Group Name</div>
<div class="col-1">
    <div class="item">Item Name
        <br>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" class="pullup">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="' . htmlspecialchars($itemID) . '"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="userIDnum" value="' . htmlspecialchars($userIDnum) . '"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="groupName" value="' . htmlspecialchars($group_name) . '"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="itemName" value="' . htmlspecialchars($item_name) . '"></input>
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile"></input>
            <br>Name:
            <input type="text" name="displayName"></input>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Vlad. This worked perfectly. Did not realize that p tags couldn't contain block elements, so appreciate the explanation on that as well!

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is the `<input type="file" name="uploadFile"></input>`

It is to large to fit in the smaller container. So the dimension of the form is to large.

Edit:

The default file input is hard to style. Use something like [uniform](http://www.jquerycode.com/theming/uniform-js/) to create a file input that fits in the box.

ps: item should be a `div` and not a `p-Tag`

Edit 2: Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mdLynt1/7/) and added:

```
input[type="file"] {
  max-width: 110px;
}
```

Works fine, if you dont need the text beside the upload button. Otherwise go for uniform.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed col-1 width to 100% but it still didn't work in the JSFiddle. I also tried changing the width of the input. Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: It can´t work, because the element is to large. You can use something like `overflow: hidden;` but i don´t think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Der. Saw your edit after accepting the other answer. Appreciate suggestion on uniform and CSS. +1